# How to reduce gap/space between bar chart and chart legend using achart engine?

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine, linechart

Hi I very new to chart applications. Now I created bar chart for my application. When I run create bar chart as separate project the output look like this.

[image]

Then When i integrate bar chart with my application. I can't display legend text below in my bar chart. How can i reduce gap/space between chart and legend text? Can anybody help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If we could see some code, would be really helpful..

Comment: @malavika Also try to give bottom margin in -ve i.e. -10 and see if it works or not.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tweak the chart margins using the `setMargins()` method:

```
mRenderer.setMargins(int[] margins);
```

The `margins` values are: `top, left, bottom, right`. The default values are: `20, 30, 10, 20`. You will need to reduce the `bottom` value.

Comment: What is `mRenderer` / how to get it?

Answer (score 2):

If we set margin and pan limit we can achieve this.

[image]

```
    mrenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20 ,60,  -20, 60 });
    mrenderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { -25, 20, -25, 40 })
```

Use these methods to reduce the space from chart to legend. Thank you.

Comment: What is `mrenderer` / how to get it?